# apex_application.g_print_success_message variable does not get set

Tags: oracle-apex

On my DML form I have a delete process that calls a PL/SQL function:

```
DECLARE
 err_code NUMBER;

BEGIN
my_package.delete_record(id => :P2_ID,error_code => err_code);

IF NVL(TO_NUMBER(err_code),0) = 0 THEN  
        apex_debug.message('Record deleted');
        apex_application.g_print_success_message := 'Record deleted';
END IF;

END;
```

Somehow apex_application.g_print_success_message does not get set and displayed even though everything else works as I see a debug message being written. Can anyone help my figure this one out? Could it be because I have multiple processes on the page?

Comment: Hi Coding Duchess, did you still need help with this? Scott explained that, while you can't set `apex_application.g_print_success_message` directly, you can assign the message to a page item and then refer to the item in the Process' success message using substitution variable syntax. Did you try that?

Comment: that was my bad, I set it in the wrong place and that is why it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Updating that variable directly is not supported.

You can define a hidden item, set that within your processes

```
:P0_MY_HIDDEN_ITEM := 'Process outcome';
```

Then include the following in the success message attribute to your final process.

[image]

Errors can be added using [apex_error](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/ADD_ERROR-Procedure-Signature-1.html#GUID-27CC02FC-F327-4D37-B63D-17EDDDEBED7E) package.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean

Comment: I didn't have this link handy yesterday, for more context https://community.oracle.com/message/13007230#13007230

Answer (score 0):

Check for the process point of yout page process, the success message won't appear on a "Before Header" process point.

If that doesn't help, check out the [apex.message](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/apex-message-namespace.htm#AEAPI-GUID-95451F4F-71A2-4CE3-8D11-B825038F8551) API.

```
 apex.message.showPageSuccess( "Record deleted" );
```

Comment: that is javascript

Answer (score 0):

Only the last assignment are shown.
So check if you have an empty assignment to it somewhere else.

```
 apex_application.g_print_success_message:='';
```

Also see if you by any chance have filled in a space in one of the page processes "Success Message"